# crontab -e issue on sun solaris fresh installation

Tags: linux, unix, solaris, cron, sunos

I'm doing server migration in sun solaris OS. And I have to migrate crontabs also with that. New server have fresh installation of solaris. In usual way while I type `crontab -l` it shows the existing cron content.

But while I type `crontab -e` it fail to load the editor. How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: Not certain about Solaris, but on some other systems `crontab -e` will attempt to launch the editor defined by `$EDITOR`. Perhaps you just need to set the environment variable to something like `EDITOR=/path/to/vi`

Comment: This kind of question is more on topic over at http://superuser.com than here at Stack Overflow, incidentally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be fixed by exporting editor variable with value `vi`. So run following command and then run `crontab -e`

```
export EDITOR=vi
crontab -e
```